# How to call vb script on button click event?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to call vb script from C#.net on button click event.But it is not working when I am using asp:button contol but when using input type= button working properly.Why this so?
I heard that vb script only run in IE not other browser.Does it so?

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing up server side code and client side code.  Yes VBScript will only run in IE (on Windows).  Also when you include your code can you also explain what you expect to happen and where.

Comment: I used from this url :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394833/on-asp-net-button-click-populate-a-asp-net-textbox-using-vb-script

Comment: <script type="text/vbscript">
        sub GetSignData()
            signData = "Hello, StackOverflow!"
            set myTextbox = document.getElementById("<%= Textbox1.ClientID %>")
            myTextbox.value = signData
        end sub
    </script>     <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Text="Hello, World!" />
        <input type="button" id="btnAccept" name="btnAccept" runat="server" value="Accept " onclick="GetSignData()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

Comment: Have you tried using the OnClientClick attribute for the asp:Button?